# How to perform AND query in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I need to fetch the Friends list **where**

```
(friendshipStatus == friendshipStatusRequested && senderId == currentUserId)
```

Seems firebase does not provide support for **AND, OR** or subqueries. Is there any way to sort out the problem?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database only supports ordering/querying on a single property. In many cases you can combine the values that you want to order/filter on into a new, synthetic property and use that in your query. For example: `"friendshipStatus_senderId": "friendshipStatusRequested_9HYZen....BLI2"`. See my longer answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Firebase doesn't support it. What you can do, is create a new attribute `friendshipUser` with the mix of those two values.

`friendshipUser = "friendshipStatusRequested_currentUserId"`